# F-vectors of simplicial complex and f-vectors of non-faces of simplicial complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, graph-theory, simplicial-complexes

Is there any result which gives us a relation between f-vector of simplicial complex and f-vector of nonfaces of a simplicial complex?

Thank you

Comment: You posted this same question about 7 hours earlier: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366005/relation-between-f-vector-and-non-faces-of-a-simplicial-complex

Comment: By a "nonface," do you mean *any* set of vertices that don't form a face or a *minimal* set of vertices that don't form a face?

Comment: A nonface means the face which are not present in the given simplicial complex.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean, but if a simplicial complex on $n$ vertices has $f_i$ $i$-dimensional faces, then it has ${n\choose i+1}-f_i$ $i$-dimensional nonfaces.